# random bsod every night

Tags: windows, bsod

I have a 64 bit  windows 10 (clean install) with no antivirus on hp Probook 4530s laptop 6go ram i5 processor and i use a 3g usb modem (huwaui e173) for internet

i've been having random bsod almost evey night , i think the problem is my usb modem i've been having a lot of problems with it, i tried installing the latest version of [software](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/products/downloads/detail/e173-en.htm?id=54449) to run it

I [attached](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=23984754657194435632) the content of minidump folder

Comment: Unplug all USB devices and see if it still does it. If it doesn't, then you'll know it's one of them, and you can connect them 1 by 1. If it does, then it's something else.

Comment: have you updated the software? Is the crash gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get always the same crash:

[Bug Check 0x9F: DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
The DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE bug check has a value of 0x0000009F. 
This bug check indicates that the driver is in an inconsistent or invalid power state.


DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe001023008d0, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd0019687f990, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe0010540cb80, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------

Implicit thread is now ffffe000`ff162800
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for cnnctfy3.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for cnnctfy3.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10240.16384.amd64fre.th1.150709-1700

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Hewlett-Packard

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  HP ProBook 4530s

SYSTEM_SKU:  A1D46EA#BH4

SYSTEM_VERSION:  A0000C02

BIOS_VENDOR:  Hewlett-Packard

BIOS_VERSION:  68SRR Ver. F.60

BIOS_DATE:  03/13/2015

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Hewlett-Packard

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  167C

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  KBC Version 22.26

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffe001023008d0

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd0019687f990

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffe0010540cb80

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

FAULTING_THREAD:  ff162800

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: 95b

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 2a

CPU_STEPPING: 7

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,2a,7,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 29'00000000 (cache) 29'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff801a88cb1d0 to fffff801a89d7656

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KiSwapContext
01 nt!KiSwapThread
02 nt!KiCommitThreadWait
03 nt!KeDelayExecutionThread
04 cnnctfy3
05 0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  cnnctfy3.sys

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_cnnctfy3!Unknown_Function

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_cnnctfy3!Unknown_Function

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_cnnctfy3!Unknown_Function

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10240.16384.amd64fre.th1.150709-1700


    Loaded symbol image file: cnnctfy3.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\cnnctfy3.sys
    Image name: cnnctfy3.sys
    Timestamp:        Fri Aug 16 19:12:46 2013 (520E5D8E)
```

The crash seams to be caused by the driver `cnnctfy3.sys`, wich seams to be part of a software called `Connectify Hotspot`.

So update the software to a Windows 10 compatible version, your driver is from 2013.

Comment: Nice answer! I was curious what debug program that output is from? It looks much cleaner with WinDbg, unless my eyes are just playing tricks on me today.

Comment: @DrZoo I use Windbg for debugging the dump